# How would I get $values that deep inside of list in SCSS?

Tags: list, function, dictionary, sass, directive

I want to call all values from each `$lists` of specific `$map` (`$value-tree` in this case.) and do to create media queries for that numbers.

The `$map` what I have looks like this:

```
$breakpoints: (
    564
    768
    992
    1200
);

$value-tree: (
    width: (
        80%, 70%, 400px, 500px
    ),
    font-size: (
        20px, 30px, 40px, 50px
    ),
    color: (
        lightblue, orange, lime, crimson
    ),
    border: (
        1px solid black, 
        4px solid orange,
        7px solid brown, 
        10px solid lightblue  
    )
);
```

And this is my code:

```
@mixin media-module($prefix, $properties...) {
    @each $names, $value in $properties {
        $myValue: map-get($names, $value);
        $myGrid: nth($breakpoints, $myValue);
        // doesn't work
        @media all and (min-width: $myGrid + px) {
            @each $names in $properties {
                #{$names}: 123;     
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is these two directives, **map-get** and **map-values** can't call the `$values` from the `$lists`.

used map-get directive to call the `$values`:

> Error: $map: "width" is not a map for 'map-get'
>           on line 112 of scss/app.scss, in 'media-module'

used map-values:

> Error: $map: "width" is not a map for `map-values'

Is there any ways to get or call the values from the `$lists` that inside of `$map`?

Many thanks always.

================ UPDATE 12/6 ================

I made it to create the numbers of media queries for each of the `$breakpoints'` values but it only calls width's values like this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 564px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 80%;
    display: 80%;
    border: 80%; } }
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 70%;
    display: 70%;
    border: 70%; } }
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 400px;
    display: 400px;
    border: 400px; } }
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 500px;
    display: 500px;
    border: 500px; } }
```

My second code looks like this:

```
@mixin mqg3($prefix, $properties...) {
    @each $contents, $dummy in $prefix, $properties {
        $myGroup: map-get($prefix, $contents);
        @each $values in $myGroup {
            $myIndex: index($myGroup, $values);
            $myGrid: nth($breakpoints, $myIndex);
            @media all and (min-width: $myGrid + px) {
                @each $names in $properties {
                    #{$names}: $values;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

P.S

Thanks for answer me @Jakob, but I want to make the `$properties` can be able to checked inside of `@include` so the user doesn't need to scroll up every time for checking the `$properties`:

> .qaz { @include mqg3($bp-values, width, display, border); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried to say in this post: [How to get $values of Array in SCSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579774/how-to-get-values-of-array-in-scss/53580146#53580146), in my opinion a nested map helps you to find a more  clear & simple solution:

```
$bp-values:(
  xs:(
    display: 564px,
    width: 200px,
    font-size: 20px,
    color:lightblue,
    border:1px solid black
  ),
  md:(
    display: 768px,
    width: 300px,
    font-size: 30px,
    color:orange,
    border:4px solid orange
  ),
  lg:(
    display: 992px,
    width: 400px,
    font-size: 40px,
    color:lime,
    border:7px solid brown
  ),
  xl:(
    display: 1200px,
    width: 500px,
    font-size: 50px,
    color:crimson,
    border:10px solid lightblue
  )
);

@mixin mqg3($map, $keys...) {
  @each $keyMap, $valueMap in $map {
    @media all and (min-width: map-get($valueMap, display)) {
      @each $v in $keys {
        #{$v}: map-get($valueMap, $v);
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

It is more clear every correlation. It is not necessary to insert the `display` in your args 'cause I suppose it is your min-width:

```
.qaz { @include mqg3($bp-values, width, border); }

.qaz1 { @include mqg3($bp-values, color, font-size); }
```

This is the result:

```
@media all and (min-width: 564px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 300px;
    border: 4px solid orange;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 400px;
    border: 7px solid brown;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 500px;
    border: 10px solid lightblue;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 564px) {
  .qaz1 {
    color: lightblue;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .qaz1 {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .qaz1 {
    color: lime;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .qaz1 {
    color: crimson;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

As you asked in the comment, if you want work with lists, this is another solution. I put your `$breakpoints` with the other lists. You can remove `display` in your args 'cause by default I use it always as `min-width`:

```
$value-tree: (
    display:(
        564, 768, 992, 1200
    ),
    width: (
        80%, 70%, 400px, 500px
    ),
    font-size: (
        20px, 30px, 40px, 50px
    ),
    color: (
        lightblue, orange, lime, crimson
    ),
    border: (
        1px solid black, 
        4px solid orange,
        7px solid brown, 
        10px solid lightblue  
    )
);

@mixin mqg3($map, $keys...){
  $myList:map-get($map, display);

  @each $myItem in $myList {
    $i: index($myList, $myItem);
    @media all and (min-width: $myItem * 1px) {
      @each $v in $keys {
        #{$v}: nth(map-get($value-tree, $v), $i);
      }
    }  
  }
}

.qaz { @include mqg3($value-tree, width, border); }
```

This is the output:

```
@media all and (min-width: 564px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 70%;
    border: 4px solid orange;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 400px;
    border: 7px solid brown;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .qaz {
    width: 500px;
    border: 10px solid lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Always thank you @ReSedano. but I'm focusing on minimizing because I think it doesn't need to write the `$properties` everytime. If there's no other way, I'll try your way.

Comment: Again, you literally saved my life. Thank you so much, respect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

**SCSS**

```
@mixin media-module {
  $index: 1;
  @each $bp in $breakpoints {
    @media all and (min-width: $bp * 1px){
      @each $key, $list in $value-tree {
        #{$key}: nth($list, $index);
      }
      $index: $index + 1; 
    }
  }
}

.class {
  @include media-module;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
@media all and (min-width: 564px) {
  .class {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .class {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: orange;
    border: 4px solid orange;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .class {
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: lime;
    border: 7px solid brown;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .class {
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: crimson;
    border: 10px solid lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Big appreciated, It's quite similar but I want to make the users can call the `$properties` inside of the `@include`. I updated my question for more detail.